# Error in Eclipse Java: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have added the mysql-connector-java-5.1.19.jar but i don't know why the error is coming. [driver is imported as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLACV.png)

```
    public class data {
    String server = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "toor";
    public int starting() {
        int id;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
            Connection incre = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("inc"+server, user, pass);
            Statement statement = (Statement) incre.createStatement();
            String select = "Select start from incr;";
            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery(select);
            if(rs.next()){
                id = rs.getInt("start");
            }
            incre.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: not sure but `driver` should be `Driver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is case sensitive, instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.driver` you need

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

However, with modern JDBC drivers this line is not required at all, so I would try removing it.